# Subir una imagen, guardarla y mostrarla durante la sesion como imagen de perfil con PHP

Tags: php, fileupload, sesiones

Quiero colocar una imágen de perfil, logro subirla al servidor y que se muestre, pero en cuanto la pagina se actualiza o recarga, la imágen ya no se muestra.

La duda que tengo es si el 'fallo' es por que tengo algo mal en el código o si debería guardar la imagen en una variable de sesión, (y de ser el caso) como tendría que hacer para guardar imágenes en variables de sesión

Este es el código que tengo en el index.php:

```
     <?php
        #muestra el mensaje de bienvenida, la imagen de perfil y el login.
        if (!existeUsuarioAsociadoEnSession()){
          login();
        }
        $archivo = (isset($_FILES['imagen'])) ? $_FILES['imagen'] : null;
        if ($archivo) {
           $extension = pathinfo($archivo['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
           $extension = strtolower($extension);
           $extension_correcta = ($extension == 'jpg' or $extension == 'jpeg' or $extension == 'gif' or $extension == 'png');
           if ($extension_correcta) {
              $ruta_destino_archivo = "images/{$archivo['name']}";
              $archivo_ok = move_uploaded_file($archivo['tmp_name'], $ruta_destino_archivo);
           }
        }
        if (isset($archivo)){
          if (!$extension_correcta){
            echo '<span style="color: #f00;"> La extensión es incorrecta, el archivo debe ser jpg, jpeg, gif o png. </span>';
          }elseif (!$archivo_ok){
            echo '<span style="color: #f00;"> Error al intentar subir el archivo. </span>';
          } else{
              echo   "<strong> El archivo ha sido subido correctamente. </strong>
                 <br />";
          }
        }
        if (existeUsuarioAsociadoEnSession()){
          echo '<h4>Elige una foto de perfi</h4>
                  <form id="upload" method="post" action="index.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <label> Archivo </label>
                    <input type="file" name="imagen" required="required" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Subir" />
                  </form>';
          echo $msg.'<br>';//muestra mensaje definido en el archivo sesion.php
          echo $img='<img class="perfil" src="images/'.  $archivo['name'] .'" alt="" />';
        }
      ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para utilizar sesiones en PHP no olvides poner `session_start()` al comienzo del archivo. Para guardar en sesión la imagen debes usar la variable `$_SESSION`, quedaría algo así:

```
// esto va al comienzo de tu archivo

session_start(); 

//así guardas en una variable de sesión tu imagen para poder utilizar siempre, 
//(hasta que cierres sesión) aunque recargues la pagina, no se perderá la imagen.

$_SESSION['imagen_perfil'] =  $archivo['name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

creo q haciendo solo un session_start();  y luego hacer una consulta a la bd donde guardaste la foto y colocango el siguiente cod en el html

```html
<img style="width: 350px; height: 350px;" src="<?php echo 'rutal de la foto '.$row['nombre del campo en la bd'];?>" class="ico"   alt="Card image cap">
```

te mostrara la imagen q desea en tu caso seria como foto de perfil